# How to add this constraint in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, check-constraints

I want to create this table. Here gender attribute is only allows 'M' or 'F'. Therefore I used constraint like this way when I was creating the table.

Description of Table :

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
    emp_no INT PRIMARY KEY,
    birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT ck_Only_Alphabets CHECK(gender IN("M", "F")),
    hire_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

This block of code works fine. I used `CONSTRAINT ck_Only_Alphabets CHECK(gender IN("M", "F"))`.

Are there any other ways to add this constraints? Please introduce other ways that I can do this.

Comment: which sql engine are you using?

Comment: @zealous I'm using wamp server.

Comment: What DB version? ... the `CHECK` constraint is ignored, depending on the version.

Comment: Check constraints or trigger are pretty much your options here.

Comment: @PaulT. T. version 8.0.18

Comment: Try with: `gender VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(gender IN("M", "F")),`

Comment: You can also build the constraint into the INSERT itself

Comment: You may use `gender ENUM('M', 'F') NOT NULL`. This allows only 2 specified values. If any non-legal value is inserted then empty string `''` will be inserted with a warning. If you don't want to allow this then enable strict SQL mode (incorrect value will generate error instead of warning).

Answer (score 0):

There are three other ways of implementing such a constraint that I can readily think of:

1. Use a trigger to check the valid values.
2. Use an enumerated type.
3. Use a reference table and a foreign key constraint.

There are also variations, such as a check constraint using a user-defined function.

I think the best method is a `check` constraint, so I see no need to elaborate on how to do any of the others.